# Shell variables. I'm new at this and having diffulculty

Tags: bash, ssh, unix

3. If the shell variable x has the value 5, and you reassign it with x="expr $x + 10", what is the new value of x?  What would have been the value if single quotes were used instead?  What is the most likely mistake in the above?

Comment: Have you tried it? If this is homework, please state that, but also show your efforts. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the new value of x would be this literal string:

```
expr 5 + 10
```

if you use single quotes instead,  the value of x would be this literal string:

```
expr $x +10
```

why the difference? because variable expansion works inside double quote but not single quote.
if you want to add 10 to x, you should really do this:

```
x=5
x=`expr $x + 10` # here is backquote
```

Comment: I run x="epr $x + 10" and it returns x=expr expr +10 +10. When I run it with single quotes it returns x=expr $x +10,

Answer (score 1):

The new value of `x` is `expr 5 + 10`. For single quotes, the value would be `expr $x + 10`. The mistake is in passing a string on the right-hand side of the assignment operator when evaluation was obviously intended.

Depending on your educational institution's policies and/or academic honor codes, you may be required, at peril of penalties up to and potentially including expulsion, to cite this Super User answer when you turn in your homework. Depending on your instructor's requirements, the citation format may differ, but in absence of specific guidance the following should serve as a reasonable default:

Miller, Aaron. Answer to "Shell variables. I'm new at this and having diffulculty [sic]" Super User. Stack Exchange, 2013. Web. November 14, 2013. 
< https://superuser.com/a/675733/162434 >

Comment: http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/Unix/HW-6.htm

Comment: It is homework, we are allowed to "google" it. Not trying to get someone to supply the answer, but do appreciate any help I can get, it is all something I have never worked with before.

Comment: @Allen Well, it's not mine to say, of course; I'm just an inveterate smartass.

Comment: that's okay, smartass I can handle. We discussed the answers in class and got more explanations. did not get an answer on why strings to the right of the operator is incorrect.

Comment: @Allen It's not *incorrect*, per se, so much as that single-quoted strings represent their contents literally, and double-quoted ones only interpolate variables (technically any string starting with `$`, but let's not overcomplicate it for now). If you actually wanted to assign the string `expr 5 + 10` to `$x`, then `$x = "expr $x + 10"` would be perfectly fine. But if you want the contents of the string evaluated like a command, and the *result* assigned to the string, you need to use backquotes instead of single- or double-quotes. That's probably what your instructor was getting at.

Comment: Now that makes sense to me. I just tried it and got a completely different result. Thank you.I'm writing it all down in my notes.